# How to mock RPi.GPIO in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to mock `RPi.GPIO` in python code to do some unit testing.

The problem I have is that my import of `RPi.GPIO` fails when called in my unit tests which do not run on the actual Raspberry Pi.

e.g.

**tests.py**

```
import iohandler
...
...
```

**iohandler.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO

def function_to_test():
    pass
```

The problem here is that for tests to run it must import `iohandler` which in turn must import `RPi.GPIO`. This fails as `RPi.GPIO` is not installed on the machine which will run the tests.

I've attempted to try and trick the modules after looking at another answer on this site as follows:

**tests.py**

```
import sys
import gpiomock # this is a file on the file system
sys.modules["RPi.GPIO"] = gpiomock.GPIO()

import iohandler # the .py file that contains the actual GPIO import
```

**gpiomock.py**

```
class GPIO():
    ...
    ...
```

As `sys.modules` is just a dictionary I would have thought this would work as I am providing a key for lookup of `RPi.GPIO` and also what I want to replace it with. However I get the following error message.

`ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO`

It feels like the *nested* structure of the actual `RPi.GPIO` library is causing this not to work.

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 5):

Managed to get this working by using this example from Reddit which I will reproduce below:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5eddp5/mock_testing_rpigpio/#ampf=undefined

**tests.py**

```
from mock import MagicMock, patch

MockRPi = MagicMock()
modules = {
    "RPi": MockRPi,
    "RPi.GPIO": MockRPi.GPIO,
}
patcher = patch.dict("sys.modules", modules)
patcher.start()

# Then for the actual test

with patch("RPi.GPIO.output") as mock_gpio:

    # Invoke the code to test GPIO
    mock_gpio.assert_called_with(....)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [Mock.GPIO](https://github.com/codenio/mock.gpio) library

after installation, you could use it as follows

```
try:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
except:
    import Mock.GPIO as GPIO
```